# Как удалить связи таблиц laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Здравствуйте, подскажите как я могу удалить связи между таблицами? 
То есть происходит удаления модели

```
$user = new User();
$user->delete();
```

И сразу же мне надо чтобы удалялись все ранее связи, то есть к примеру комментарии (у меня комментарии привязаны 1 ко многим к пользователю), а то получается так, что удаляю, и сразу выскакивает ошибка, что есть связь между ними, и удалить нельзя в итоге
Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Покажите файл миграций, пожалуйста. возможно Вам надо указать `->onDelete('cascade');` для ключей..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Вариант 1, используя модели и связи

Ты не указал связи таблиц пользователя и других, буду считать что у тебя есть 2 таблицы:

1. **User** - Модель пользователей
2. **Comments** - модель комментариев

Первое, тебе нужно сделать выборку конкретного пользователя

```
$user = User::find($id);
```

Второе: В моделях у тебя должны быть выстроены связи таблиц (relations)

```
// Удаление комментариев у пользователя
$user->comments()->delete();
```

И в заключении удаляешь самого пользователя

```
$user->delete();
```

#### Вариант 2, используя стандартные связки foreign keys в БД

Для этого, тебе необходимо установить связку foreign keys при миграции, которая будет на уровне БД следить за целостностью данных.
Вот пример:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('comments')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Такая связка автоматически будет удалять все комментарии у пользователя, в случае удаления его из таблицы БД

#### Вариант 3, использовать ивенты в моделях (laravel)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events

Comment: Благодарю, помогло)